# background-size: 100% 100% doesn't work after uploading

Tags: html, django, background-size

I have a Django site, and when I run it on my local machine everything is fine, but when I make it to pythonanywhere.com one little problem appears: somewhy and somehow my background image doesn't want to fill the whole page even though it does on my local host (using the same browser, so the problem is not here). Basically I don't mind changing the aspect ratio, I just want each pixel of the background to be fully on the screen, would it be either 600x400 or 200x2000.

```
body {
    background: url("images/classes.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

It seems to me like `{background-size: 100% 100%}` just... doesn't work?

I tried to switch percents to `100vw 100vh`, but the output was literally the same.

Page itself: http://seltsamermann.pythonanywhere.com/classes/

Image itself: https://i.ibb.co/0G86wL2/classes.jpg

I wonder what might be the problem.

(in case that might help somehow)
https://github.com/Seltsamermann/Specs-SL-PvP/blob/master/main/templates/main/classes.html
https://github.com/Seltsamermann/Specs-SL-PvP/blob/master/main/static/main/style_classes.css

Comment: That looks like it's working to me. Are you sure your browser hasn't cached an old version?

Comment: Do you mean that when you're opening the page link you may see the whole picture and not just part of it, as if it was "covering" the screen? If yes, that's kinda weird because actually I thought of this before and tried another browser but got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The object-fit CSS property sets how the content of a replaced element, such as an `<img>` or `<video>`, should be resized to fit its container. Use this propriety for the image in your css, or the container that stores that image.

```
object-fit: cover;
```

For more : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Try this:

```
body {
  background: url("") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly it doesn't work for me, or I just misunderstood you. My "image" is a background of HTML <body> block, so I added ```object-fit: fill;``` to my ```body {}``` part of CSS (because I actually need a "fill" and not "cover" as I understand), but nothing have changed.

Comment: I've edited my answer, that worked for me on my local machine, I hope it works after upload too. And remove the <body background=""> from HTML, leave only the css background.

Comment: Tried it; works on my local machine too, but somewhy after upload it doesn't. :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically I just outplayed myself; the real problem was the version control, I just missed several things. Code in the main post works totally fine.